# E: Unable to locate package ultra-flat-theme (from noobslab PPA) in 17.04

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

For any package I attempt to install via terminal, such as `ultra-flat-theme`, I get the following:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
 themes uploaded on http://www.NoobsLab.com PPA
For exact theme version and support visit on site and see themes page
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpsrvv19_r/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpsrvv19_r/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key D530E028F59EAE4D: public key "Launchpad PPA for NoobsLab" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
OK
```

The I enter `sudo apt-get update` the results of which appears to work fine.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ultra-flat-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ultra-flat-theme
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is for everything I've tried.  
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install humanity-colors`
Gets me the same thing, for instance.

Comment: It just let me install Gparted via `sudo apt-get install`.  I do have Canonical Partners repositories enabled in Software & Updates.

Comment: both of the packages you've tried have no release candidate for zesty https://launchpad.net/~ravefinity-project/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, can you try a package that has?

Comment: it's just from those PPAs. 17.04 has just been released, so it's not surprising that there aren't packages for it yet in PPAs. You may have to be patient (or if you really want the theme, use 16.04 instead)

Comment: Such as?  Also, I followed that link and it would appear that it does have a candidate for zesty, if I select zesty in the dropdown box under "Technical Details" it gives me a option for zesty.

Comment: Okay, I see.  I'll just hold my horses. ;)

Comment: The dropdown search is confusing - if you look at the results you can see they are for wily, trusty, xenial... Kind of annoying!

Comment: The PPA shows many themes available for Zesty, but the last release for `ultra-flat-theme` was for xenial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author hasn't carried forward all of their themes to zesty yet. You can see which ones are available by using Synaptic, and selecting the Origin view.

You can download the xenial version directly at https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes/+files/ultra-flat-theme_2.2~xenial~NoobsLab.com_all.deb and hopefully it'll still work in zesty.

And re: "*I followed that link and it would appear that it does have a candidate for zesty, if I select zesty in the dropdown box under "Technical Details" it gives me a option for zesty.*"

That dropdown is only for filling out the deb statements shown just below the dropdown.